# View the html designer within VS 2012 without switching to Blend

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, winjs

I am using VS2012 for creating html/javascript type of app for windows 8 store. When I create a html file, there is no way for me to view the html file unless I launch it in the blend. Sometimes when I am working in code and making changes in html also, I find it a bit annoying to keep switching between VS and blend. Is there anyway to view HTML designer within VS 2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry Paul. This is currently limited to Blend. Blend is the UI design tool of choice for Windows Store apps currently as it's got quite a few extra features above Visual Studio for HTML and XAML support.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Hopefully someday this will be available or somehow little easier to use